# SAS ods pdf footnote on 2 lines

Tags: pdf, sas, ods, footnotes

I would like to output a SAS result in a pdf file. In the footnote, I would like to have 2 lines on the right bottom of the page:

- Doc Research
- Page 1 of 10

Here is an example:

```
options nodate nonumber;
data work.animals;
    input name $ weight;
    datalines;
    monkey 20
    shark 500
    lion 200
    wolf 120
    buffalo 400
    ;
run;

ods pdf file = 'C:\sasdata\animals.pdf';
ods escapechar= '!';
proc print data=work.animals;
    title 'Animals';
    footnote j = r 'Page !{thispage} of !{lastpage}';
run;
ods pdf close;
ods listing;
```

Comment: line 1 : Doc Research; line 2 : Page 1 of 20

Comment: `footnote` is the same as `footnote1`.  You can specify up to 10 Footnotes, `footnote1` through `footnote10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
footnote j = r "Doc Research !{newline} Page !{thispage} of !{lastpage}";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works but I have this as result: Doc Reserach (line 1) ; Page 1 of     20  (line 2) and I have an extra free space between of and 20 (of     20)

Comment: Can you try wrapping it up using a ````strip()```` function?

Comment: I will try... Thanks